# Invalid object name dbo.tbLanguage - ASP.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I got a problem with my asp site, when I tried to connect to home page, it said

```
"Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.tbLanguage'"
```

It's very weird because when I created a new file named "abc.html" and then type
"localhost/abc.html" it run into this error again.

I think this error caused by server not my code, but how can I fix that.
Thanks

Comment: maybe a typo `dbo.tbLanguage` vs. e.g. `dbo.tblLanguage`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a simple mistake about set `tblLanguage` to `tbLanguage`
Please Check it

Answer (score 0):

thank for interesting about this, I've just checked it and I find out that, table "tbLanguage" is missed. I got problem when I migrate database from localhost to server.
Thanks